# How does ghostscript compress PDFs when it applies a greyscale?

Tags: compression, ghostscript

I have a single paged PDF that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH6xK.jpg) that is 6.3 MB. Because it seems to already be in greyscale in the first place, applying a greyscale should not make a huge difference.

But when I apply a greyscale to the PDF with:

```
gs \
 -sOutputFile=output.pdf \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
 -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray \
 -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray \
 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
 -dNOPAUSE \
 -dBATCH \
 input.pdf
```

"output.pdf" is only 128.4 kB, and you can see the presence of new artifacts.  The artifacts are not noticeable when the PDF is at full scale, but if you zoom in you can clearly tell a difference. You can see the greyscaled image [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zgAx.jpg)

What is occuring in the ghostscript that causes the artifacts? But also more importantly, what causes such a dramatic loss in file size?

EDIT:

I think I overstated the artifacts in the output file. For all intensive purposes, the files look very similar.

Version: GPL Ghostscript 9.23

Here is the original PDF file: https://send.firefox.com/download/e47df175af/#tdZSodyN2CuQL8X0VIFC1g

Here is the greyscaled PDF:
https://send.firefox.com/download/a63b3d641c/#ce9Ctu6obfXlvvNZJvPnUA

I found that Sribd, Imgur compressed the original PDF file, so there was no point in using a hoster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supplying PNG images, rather than the actual PDF files, makes it impossible for anyone to be able to tell for certain what your problem is. If you had posted the PDF files I'd be able to look and tell you.

However, I'm going to guess that you are using an older version of Ghostscript (again you don't say), and that the image in the original file is DCT (JPEG) compressed.

Because you haven't specified a particular compression method, the pdfwrite device (not Ghostscript, but the Ghostscript device which writes PDF files) uses 'Automatic' compression. It writes the image data multiple times with different compression filters, and selects the one which produces the smallest output.

Almost certainly this will again be the DCT (JPEG) compression filter, it almost invariably produces the smallest output. This is also the default filter which is used if you disable automatic selection and don't specify a different compression filter to use.

The problem is that DCT is a lossy compression, so every time you decompress and recompress it, you lose fidelity. Though the image size in bytes does decrease each time.

So that's the reason for both your results; the compression artefacts and at least part of the reduction in size. It may also be the case that your original Grayscale image is actually not Gray but RGB (or Lab or CalRGB, or ICCBased...), in which case converting it to grayscale will result in a decrease in size of 66%. Without seeing the file I can't tell.

Note that current versions of Ghostscript use a JPEG passthrough feature. Provided that the image is not being downsampled, or having its colour space altered, the image is not decompressed. It is passed unchanged to the output device, which embeds it unchanged. This avoids the artefacts introduced by decompression and recompression.

Obviously if you want to change the colour space, then the pdfwrite device does have to manipulate the image, so it has to decompress it.

You can **select** the compression filter you want to use, instead of permitting automatic selection, by using the GrayImageFilter distiller parameter see [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/VectorDevices.htm#PDFWRITE).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I added the original PDF files if you want to look at them.

Comment: The original PDF has a number of images (not just one) all of them are in DeviceRGB. The output file has all the images in DeviceGray, as specified on the command line. So that's 2/3 of the difference right there :-) Because you are altering the colour space, the images get decompressed and recompressed, and that's where both the image artefacts and the remaining reduction in image size come from.